# ARC Strong property Enumeration Error

Tags: objective-c, properties, automatic-ref-counting, enumeration

I have the following code and am getting this error before compiling:

> Fast Enumeration Variables can't be modified in ARC by default, declare the variable _strong to allow this

```
for (NSString *name in array){
        @try {
            S3ObjectController *localS3 = [[S3ObjectController alloc]init];
            name = localS3.stringProperty;
}
```

In this `S3ObjectController` class, I have the property declared like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong)  NSString *stringProperty;
```

How should I change the property? I thought I was declaring it strong?

Comment: Looks to me it should be `localS3.stringProperty = name;`, not the other way around.

Comment: Do you guys know WHY this error occurs? The default is __strong, so the variable `name` should have already been `__strong` in the for loop as it existed? `for (NSString *name in array)`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is \_\_strong required in fast enumeration loops with ARC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18387281/why-is-strong-required-in-fast-enumeration-loops-with-arc)

Comment: @KurtSpindler: I'm ten years late, but while the default in normal code is `__strong`, in fast enumeration variables, the default is (implicitly) `const __strong`. So, by explicitly declaring it `__strong`, you allow it to be modified from within the loop.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

It means declare the fast enumeration variable strong, not your instance variable:

```
for (NSString __strong *name in array) {
    @try {
        S3ObjectController *localS3 = [[S3ObjectController alloc]init];
        name = localS3.stringProperty;
    }
}
```